# What is the best way to show 3 items per click from jquery data

Tags: javascript, jquery, masonry

This is my markup:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
    var $container = $('#homegrid').masonry({
        isAnimated: true,
        itemSelector: '.home-blocks',
        columnWidth: '.grid-sizer',
        percentPosition: true,
        transitionDuration: '0',
        visibleStyle: { transform: 'translateY(0)', opacity: 1 },
        hiddenStyle: { transform: 'translateY(100px)', opacity: 0 },
    });
   jQuery('#more').click(function(){
        jQuery.get('/pages/ajax', function( data ) {

            // Make jQuery object from HTML string
            var $moreBlocks = jQuery( data );
            
            // Append new blocks
            $container.append( $moreBlocks );

            // Have Masonry position new blocks
            $container.masonry( 'appended', $moreBlocks );
        }); 
    }); 

});
```

```html
<div class="homegrid-wrap">
   <div id="homegrid" class="home-grid">
       <div class="grid-sizer"></div>
       <div class="home-blocks"></div>
       <div class="home-blocks"></div>       
       <div class="home-blocks"></div>
       <div class="home-blocks"></div>
       <div class="home-blocks"></div>
       <div class="home-blocks"></div>
       <div class="home-blocks"></div>
   </div>
   <button id="more">Load More</button>
</div>
```

What I would like to do is to count all the object that was from another html page and show 3 objects at a time per click then hide the load more button once all the objects are shown. Been working on this for days. I'm using Masonry for my grid.

Disclaimer: I dont know much about javascript.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#more').click(function(){debugger;
  var expanded = $('.block-collapsed').slice(0,3);
  expanded.show();
  expanded.removeClass('block-collapsed');
  if($('.block-collapsed').length == 0) {
      $(this).hide();
  }
});
```

```css
.home-blocks {
  width:100%;
  background-color:yellow;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.block-collapsed {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="homegrid-wrap">
   <div id="homegrid" class="home-grid">
       <div class="grid-sizer"></div>
       <div class="home-blocks block-collapsed">1</div>
       <div class="home-blocks block-collapsed">2</div>       
       <div class="home-blocks block-collapsed">3</div>
       <div class="home-blocks block-collapsed">4</div>
       <div class="home-blocks block-collapsed">5</div>
       <div class="home-blocks block-collapsed">6</div>
       <div class="home-blocks block-collapsed">7</div>
   </div>
   <button id="more">Load More</button>
</div>
```